# Can't uninstall Anything, how do I fix this?

Tags: applications

I tried to uninstall Vivaldi Web Browser but I am getting this error:

```
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package vivaldi-preview (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
```

Then I deleted a folder as admin user using the pantheon-files. I think this may be the problem. But I don't know how to fix it.
And now I can't uninstall anything because the following error happens:

```
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package vivaldi-preview (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 vivaldi-preview
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Do you remember which folder you deleted?

Comment: the folder was opt/vivaldi-something

Comment: Vivaldi isn't in the default software sources. Where did you install it from?

Comment: How did you install it in the first place and what did you do to uninstall it? Add this information to your question please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I find out what to do. First I need to download the vivaldi .deb file from the official website and place it on my home folder. Them run:

```
dpkg -i vivaldi*
```

This will install vivaldi agian with the dependencies. Now you can remove it using:

```
apt-get remove vivaldi-preview
```

Comment: Yes, but you probably won't be able to uninstall anything else. Because of it, I don't think that this should be an accepted answer. Maybe you should look at other suggestions?

Comment: Well I've been able to uninstall a bunch of things since them, no problem at the moment. And that was the solution I found so that's why for me is an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can try reinstalling vivaldi-preview and then remove / purge it. This should recreate whatever folder you deleted.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall vivaldi-preview
   ```
2. You can try running forced purge

   ```
   sudo dpkg -P --force-all vivaldi-preview
   ```
3. You can combine it and run forced remove with reinstall required

   ```
   dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq --remove vivaldi-preview
   ```
4. You can try editing /etc/init.d/vivaldi-preview to fool dpkg that post-installation script did some job and returned success

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   exit 0
   ```

Comment: ok, I tried running 1, 2 and 3 but non of them work. Whem I run 1 I get 
this error 

E: Internal Error, No file name for vivaldi-preview:amd64

and when I run 2 and 3:
 
dpkg: error processing package vivaldi-preview (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric

4 Can't find a file named vivaldi-preview on that folder.

Comment: @AndréHeringer I'm out of ideas. Try searching for solutions with your output, solutions for ubuntu will apply so you can very well ask on askubuntu. Just remember you can always answer your own questions if you happen to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu type:

```
sudo apt-get remove vivaldi-snapshot
```

Comment: Hey Alex, welcome to elementary OS stack exchange. I believe that you are receiving downvotes here because this is not Ubuntu stack exchange. For future references, answers should be for elementary OS.